# why use CROSS_COMPILE variable when we compile C code Makefile?

Tags: android, c, linux, gcc, makefile

So I want to cross compile my source code using `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc`
so for this, I write simple C code into files like `main.c` and main.h now make "Makefile" and write code into this file like,

```
     CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
     SRC=adc.c
     INC=./
     OBJ=si7006

     all:
             $(CC) $(SRC) -I$(INC) -o $(OBJ)

     clean:
             rm -rf $(OBJ)
```

now I have 2 questions 
(1) What is the use of -I$(INC) without it "make" is working file
(2) After writing Makefile I use "make" command to compile it so when I used only "make" it show errors like,

> arm-linux-androideabi-gcc adc.c -I./ -o adc make:
>
> arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found make: *** [all] Error 127

if I add CROSS_COMPILE variable at make line (Ex:- make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi- ) it working file why ??

-> so the solution is export CC="arm-linux-androideabi-gcc" and then use "make" command only for compile the Makefile and the output is like,
         arm-linux-androideabi-gcc adc.c -I./ -o adc

Comment: Is `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc` in your `$PATH`? Perhaps add it, or specify the full absolute path to `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc`.

Comment: Regarding `-I$(INC)`, that tells the compiler to find header files in the `$(INC)` directory. If there are no actual header files needed there then that option is not strictly required.

Comment: Suggest you compare the command line output from the CROSS_COMPILE case to see what the difference is. Please add that output to the question.

Comment: yes, Thank you kaylum , I get my answer

Comment: And the answer is? You can add an answer to your own question if it'll be helpful for others.

Comment: yes ohk i add my answer in my post thanks